# Java Background image not showing on Mac

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm new to Java and am trying to create a program in Swing following an Youtube Tutorial. Everything works fine in Windows but in Mac, the background image doesn't show up but only the menuBar(JLabel). I hope to get background image and JLabels in a same page.

Can someone please help me to continue in the right direction? I will put all the file codes so that understading the issue is better.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
[Main.java]
package dynamic_beat_4;

public class Main {
    
    public static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1280;
    public static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 720;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        new DynamicBeat();

    }

}


[Dynamic Beat.java]
package dynamic_beat_4;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DynamicBeat extends JFrame {

    private Image screenImage;
    private Graphics screenGraphic;

    private Image introBackground = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("../images/introBackground(Title).jpg"))
            .getImage();
    private JLabel menuBar = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("../images/menuBar.png")));

    public DynamicBeat() {
        setUndecorated(true);
        setTitle("Dynamic Beat Game");
        setSize(Main.SCREEN_WIDTH, Main.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        setLayout(null);

        menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 30);
        add(menuBar);

        Music introMusic = new Music("introMusic.mp3", true);
        introMusic.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        screenImage = createImage(Main.SCREEN_WIDTH, Main.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        screenGraphic = screenImage.getGraphics();
        screenDraw(screenGraphic);
        g.drawImage(screenImage, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void screenDraw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(introBackground, 0, 0, null);
        paintComponents(g);
        this.repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like it isn't finding the .jpg file. You should add an intermediate step where you check if `Main.class.getResource` is returning null.

Comment: it finds .jpg file. there's no syntax or nullpointer errors. for example, if I put "paintComponents(g)"( inside of screenDraw method) before "g.drawImage(introBackground, 0, 0, null);" line, it shows only background image not menuBar.

Comment: If you put 'paintComponents(g)' before `drawImage`, then the drawImage will overwrite everything you already painted on the image. If you put paintComponents(g) after then all of the components will get painted over the image. Don't call paintComponents, I've created an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some major points.

- don't call repaint inside of a paint method. This doesn't make sense.
- the preferred painting technique of swing is to override paintComponent.
- Don't override [Window#paint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)) and if you do, call `super.paint(g)`. (As per the linked javadoc.)
- Calling `paintComponents(g)` with the graphics object of a temporary image is unnecessary at best. Swing handles buffering.

I'm amazed this worked on any platform.

I think the easiest fix for this is to create a JPanel.

```
public DynamicBeat() {
    setUndecorated(true);
    setTitle("Dynamic Beat Game");
    setSize(Main.SCREEN_WIDTH, Main.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(introBackground, 0, 0, this);
        }
    };
    panel.setLayout(null);
    menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 30);
    panel.add(menuBar);
    
    setContentPane(panel);
    
    Music introMusic = new Music("introMusic.mp3", true);
    introMusic.start();
}
```

You might want to refer to this [painting in awt and swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html).

Some further tips, don't extend JFrame, and do your GUI work on the EDT.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your help. I will refer to that link and will study more on it! :D